# xcodebuild can't sign ios application although the developer certificate and provisioning profile are installed

Tags: ios, xcode, teamcity, xcodebuild

There is one logged-in user in xCode, but I need to build on behalf of another user. From this user there is a fresh iPhone Developer certificate and corresponding provisioning profile. 
- The certificate is installed in the keychain. 
- Provisioning profile is installed in the correct Xcode directory.

xcodebuild passes that user's Team Id:

```
xcodebuild archive \
     -workspace XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.xcworkspace \
     -scheme XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
     -archivePath ./XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.xcarchive \
     -destination generic/platform=iOS \
     IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0 \
     TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1" \
     CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.entitlements \
     DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=$teamId \ 
     -parallelizeTargets \
     -jobs 4 \
     -verbose \
     ENABLE_BITCODE=NO \
     CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS=NO \
     GCC_WARN_ABOUT_DEPRECATED_FUNCTIONS=NO \
     CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS=NO \
     -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

Signing does not work:

```
Check dependencies
[08:44:01][Step 8/14] Code Signing Error: No account for team "XXXXXXXXXX". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.
[08:44:01][Step 8/14] Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx'.
[08:44:01][Step 8/14] Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
```

What didn't help:

- Clean xCode's cache (just removing the folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)
- Cleaning the keychain from expired certificates
- Checked TeamId and appId to match exactly developer.apple.com
- It turned out that Mac has 2 copies of xcode. Both copies deleted. One is reinstalled.

---

there are 2 errors left after deleting the parameter -allowProvisioningUpdates:

```
[09:16:31][Step 8/14] Check dependencies
[09:16:31][Step 8/14] Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
[09:16:31][Step 8/14] Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
```

---

If I open project from xCode, disable auto-signing, select provisioning profiles, start the archive build, it is successfully completed. But I need to build project from command line (TeamCity)

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of Xcode installed? That can cause issues with locating signing assets sometimes

Comment: if you want to install on behalf of another user you need to install .p12 certificate generated from mac of user with whom's CSR  developer certificate was generated.

Comment: @NSNoob, there really were two XCode's apps. But removing the excess did not help.

Comment: @Abu Ul Hassan, The certificate was generated on another Mac, exported to P12 format, moved to the problematic Mac, and imported to the keychain. The certificate is visible in the keychain.

Comment: @pier_nasos Did the other guy export the certificate **with the private key**? That's a common mistake some people make, which makes the certificate all but useless on other macs

Comment: There are two Mac. The first one is my personal. On it I created CSR file, logged in developer.apple.com (for customer), created AppId, develop certificate and provisioning profile. Downloaded the certificate, installed in my keychain, exported to p12. Sert.p12 and provisioning profile passed to another Mac where the program is being built.

Comment: The imported certificate is visible in the list and I can "expand" it and see the key icon + user name.